# What's causing my NSExtension crash?

Tags: ios, crash, ios-app-extension

Just released a new version of an app, and it's started crashing with

> **Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException***
>   -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]: key cannot be nil

The problem seems to lie with a call to `-[NSExtension _reallyBeginExtensionRequestWithInputItems:listenerEndpoint:completion:]` on a background thread, which in turn is trying to set some nil dictionary key…

```
0   CoreFoundation          __exceptionPreprocess
1   libobjc.A.dylib         objc_exception_throw
2   CoreFoundation          _CFArgv
3   CoreFoundation          -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]
4   Foundation              -[NSExtension _reallyBeginExtensionRequestWithInputItems:listenerEndpoint:completion:]
5   libdispatch.dylib       _dispatch_call_block_and_release
6   libdispatch.dylib       _dispatch_client_callout
7   libdispatch.dylib       _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp
8   libdispatch.dylib       _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp
9   libdispatch.dylib       _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp
10  libdispatch.dylib       _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_wqthread
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib start_wqthread
```

The problem I have is that the app doesn't have any extensions - so I'm wondering what why this method is being called. The only reference I can find to this method is in [this post](https://medium.com/@avaidyam/nsextension-pluginkit-a-brief-intro-2803be91a777) but that's not much help.

The app *used* to have Share and Photo Editing extensions many versions ago, but these were long since removed.

According Crashlytics, this seems to be happening about 1 in 10 app sessions. I've seen it once on launch, so I'm assuming that's where it's happening for others too - but apart from that I'm unable to recreate.

Any thoughts on what might be causing this?

---

*Update… 6 Mar 18*

Adding some logging in the production app seemed to show the problem was occurring when presenting a `UIIMagePickerController`

Then I managed to catch an exception, which seems to confirm the issue really is with the image picker…

```
#0  0x000000018279c4f0 in objc_exception_throw ()
#1  0x00000001834ebc9c in _CFThrowFormattedException ()
#2  0x0000000183420ae8 in -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] ()
#3  0x0000000183f41f5c in -[NSExtension _reallyBeginExtensionRequestWithInputItems:listenerEndpoint:completion:] ()
#4  0x00000001029dd2cc in _dispatch_call_block_and_release ()
#5  0x00000001029dd28c in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#6  0x00000001029ebf80 in _dispatch_queue_serial_drain ()
#7  0x00000001029e07ec in _dispatch_queue_invoke ()
#8  0x00000001029ecf6c in _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh ()
#9  0x00000001029f4020 in _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread ()
#10 0x000000018317af1c in _pthread_wqthread ()
#11 0x000000018317ab6c in start_wqthread ()

Enqueued from PlugInKit reply:com.apple.mobileslideshow.photo-picker (Thread 3) Queue : PlugInKit reply:com.apple.mobileslideshow.photo-picker (serial)
#0  0x00000001029ecabc in _dispatch_queue_push ()
#1  0x0000000183f430b4 in __79-[NSExtension beginExtensionRequestWithInputItems:listenerEndpoint:completion:]_block_invoke ()
#2  0x0000000183f4628c in __33-[NSExtension _safelyBeginUsing:]_block_invoke_4 ()
#3  0x0000000188a2a2f8 in __28-[PKHostPlugIn startPlugIn:]_block_invoke.143 ()
#4  0x0000000188a2be1c in __28-[PKHostPlugIn startPlugIn:]_block_invoke_2.292 ()
#5  0x000000018355aad0 in __invoking___ ()
#6  0x000000018343936c in -[NSInvocation invoke] ()
#7  0x00000001029dd2cc in _dispatch_call_block_and_release ()
#8  0x00000001029dd28c in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#9  0x00000001029ebf80 in _dispatch_queue_serial_drain ()
#10 0x00000001029e07ec in _dispatch_queue_invoke ()
#11 0x00000001029ecf6c in _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh ()
#12 0x00000001029f4020 in _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread ()
#13 0x000000018317af1c in _pthread_wqthread ()
#14 0x000000018317ab6c in start_wqthread ()

Enqueued from com.apple.NSXPCConnection.user.com.apple.mobileslideshow.photo-picker (Thread 4) Queue : com.apple.NSXPCConnection.user.com.apple.mobileslideshow.photo-picker (serial)
#0  0x00000001029ecabc in _dispatch_queue_push ()
#1  0x0000000188a28ed4 in -[PKHostPlugIn connection:handleInvocation:isReply:] ()
#2  0x0000000184071878 in -[NSXPCConnection _decodeAndInvokeReplyBlockWithEvent:sequence:replyInfo:] ()
#3  0x0000000184075cb0 in __88-[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:orArguments:count:methodSignature:selector:withProxy:]_block_invoke.346 ()
#4  0x00000001831b5d44 in _xpc_connection_reply_callout ()
#5  0x00000001831b5c80 in _xpc_connection_call_reply_async ()
#6  0x00000001029ddaa4 in _dispatch_client_callout3 ()
#7  0x00000001029f7cd4 in _dispatch_mach_msg_async_reply_invoke ()
#8  0x00000001029ebd9c in _dispatch_queue_serial_drain ()
#9  0x00000001029e07ec in _dispatch_queue_invoke ()
#10 0x00000001029ecf6c in _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh ()
#11 0x00000001029f4020 in _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread ()
#12 0x000000018317af1c in _pthread_wqthread ()
#13 0x000000018317ab6c in start_wqthread ()

Enqueued from com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit (Thread 4) Queue : com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit (serial)
#0  0x00000001029f58f8 in _dispatch_mach_reply_merge_msg ()
#1  0x00000001029fadec in _dispatch_event_loop_merge ()
#2  0x00000001029f3f70 in _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread ()
#3  0x000000018317af1c in _pthread_wqthread ()
#4  0x000000018317ab6c in start_wqthread ()
```

Does this give anyone a clue?

---

*Update… 2 8 Mar 2018*

**More details**

- The app is built for iOS 11+, and the crash occurs on all iOS 11
  versions, and all devices.
- The crash occurs about as frequently at the production version when running through Xcode. Runs fine a few times, then crashes on the next run, then works fine again.
- The app uses Firebase analytics, AdMob & Fabric

Comment: Hi! While you might not have any embedded extensions, Apple does do an extension lookup for typical share/action extensions for UITextView and the like. I suggest a breakpoint on the method and `bt` in the debugger, to try and wrangle the origin of the dispatch call - and that'll be your first real clue.

Comment: Thanks! After reading your blog post I added a breakpoint on `[NSExtension beginExtensionRequestWithInputItems:completion:]` but yet to get it to crash again myself

Comment: It could be due to info plist for oder versions.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan Thanks for the suggestion, but I couldn't find anything in the `info.plist` that looked out of place

Comment: @AdityaVaidyam success! (at least, partially). See the update to my question.

Comment: @AshleyMills That's a good first step, but unfortunately if it's in UIImagePickerController, it's less likely you'll be able to fix it. Can you reproduce this bug in a clean-slate application? Is it linked to a particular device class or all devices? Any idea why it's one in ten launches that crash - are you doing something in particular each 10 launches?

Comment: Looking at the NSExtension (Foundation) assembly, it looks like you're encountering either a `nil` `serviceConnection` or `nil` `extensionContext`; I'm not sure why, if it's an UIKit component.

Comment: " on a background thread, which in turn is trying to set some nil dictionary key…" 
according to this  well i could be possible that when block runs in background the values you are setting may become nil ..... as you know background thread runs after some delay.

Comment: @AdityaVaidyam More updates to the question. As it occurs pretty regularly in a debug build I'll give the clean-state app a go.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan This is called when `UIImagePickerController` is presented - I can't influence which queue this is run on.